# access a foreach value in response section logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hdinsight, azure-logic-apps

while accessing the data iterated over foreach is not visible outside of foreach loop, Even if i can access then again foreach is loaded automatically.

can somone explain about this typical behavior of foreach in logic app
?

SS for your reference :
[image]

Timely help would much appreciated...

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

The output of an action called within a ForEach would be an array of objects. You can use the square bracket operator in case you want one specific item or any of the collection functions as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#functions